# KeyEvent on focus JavaFX FXML

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-2, javafx-8, fxml

I am currently working on an instant messaging program and have created a text  for the user to enter a message in the FXML.

How do I add a `KeyEvent` for when enter is pressed while the text field has focus.

**Update - Tried, but doesn't work**

```
<TextArea fx:id="area_chatInput"
       editable="true"
       prefHeight="60"
       prefWidth="300"
       wrapText="true"
       promptText="Enter Message />


@FXML
private void keyListener(KeyEvent event){
    if(event.getCode() == KeyCode.ENTER){
        System.out.println("enter pressed");
        sendMsg();
        event.consume();
    }
}
```

Comment: Add a KeyEvent to which code? please share a concise version of your code.

Comment: please be precise in your question - you have a _TextArea_ in your code and are talking about a _TextField_

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add `onKeyPressed` event listener to your `TextField` in the `fxml`.

```
...
<TextField fx:id="chatText" layoutX="199.0" layoutY="174.0" onKeyPressed="#keyListener" />
...
```

In the controller, declare a method `keyListener`

```
public void keyListener(KeyEvent event){
    if(event.getCode() == KeyCode.ENTER) {
          // Do stuff
          ((TextField)event.getSource()).clear(); // clear textfield
          System.out.println("Enter Pressed"); // print a message
     }
}
```

**Update - According to comments**

To avoid the cursor step to next line, you need to *consume* the event, before it leaves the method.

```
...
if (event.getCode() == KeyCode.ENTER) {
     ...
     event.consume(); // Consume Event
}
...
```

Comment: Thanks, but I am doing this in a text area where ENTER automatically adds a line break. So how do I make the keyListener method override that

Comment: It still is just adding the line break, I posted my code for clarity

Comment: @Josh your code doesn't have `onKeyPress` listener on the textarea.

Comment: your answer is suboptimal (triggered by the unprecise question, concededly :-) - in a TextField you would most probably use a semantic onAction event handler vs a low-level on onKeyWhatever event handler

Comment: @kleopatra The question was very precise. The OP wanted to know how to add a `KeyEvent` to a Control on focus. May be he has plans to replace `Enter` with something else, but again, that is not something which I can comment on :)

Comment: _when enter is pressed while the text field has focus_, in her code `<TextArea ...` - in your code: `<TextField... ` and `if (event.getCode() == KeyCode.ENTER) {... ` for a textField that's simply wrong (the rule is to always go for the highest abstraction available). If you want to take the blame so be it ... :)

Comment: talking about being precise (nitpicking, of course, my gut still has Monday :-) you never  _add a KeyEvent_ (that's done by the system), you add a _handler for an event_

Comment: I am aware of the point you are trying to make here. But as `setOnAction` is not true for all the controls (e.g. TextArea), it is not a generalized solution. I agree with it not being `optimal` incase of TextField though :P

Comment: I give up. *White Flag..* :/